# XGBoost Error when using xgboost function

Tags: r, xgboost

Here is my code:

```
xgb <- xgboost(data = as.matrix(df_all_combined), 
               label = as.matrix(target_train), 
               eta = 0.1,
               max_depth = 15, 
               nround=100, 
               subsample = 0.5,
               colsample_bytree = 0.5,
               seed = 1,
               eval_metric = "auc",
               objective = "binary:logistic",
               num_class = 12,
               nthread = 3)
```

Getting the below Error:

> Error in xgb.iter.update(bst$handle, dtrain, iteration - 1, obj) : 
>     [09:17:34] amalgamation/../src/objective/regression_obj.cc:90: Check failed: (preds.size()) == (info.labels.size()) labels are not correctly providedpreds.size=840756, label.size=70063

Could anyone help me out to solve this issue? Not able to figure out the issue.

Comment: Ask a question with more discription. It will help for others to answer.

Comment: looks like its saying something about the size of labels not matching data dimensions. Example data that reproduces the error makes helping much more feasible.

Comment: It would help if you provide a small sample of data. Change the names of any sensitive field if necessary.

Answer (score 7):

Try remove num_class = 12 from your parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The error says:
`labels are not correctly provided preds.size=840756, label.size=70063`

This means that number of rows in `df_all_combined` does not correspond to the number of rows in `target_train`

So `target_train` should be of the shape (840756,)

Answer (score 0):

Xgboost has a bug with multiclass classification. It uses preds.size () = info.labels.size() * num_classes, while using 'auc' which is wrong. So use any other metric like merror.

Answer (score 0):

The Objective and num_class donot seem to be in sync 
From xgboost parameter description :
objective "binary:logistic: logistic regression for binary classification, output probability"

And in your question the mentioned num_class =12 ,this seems to be a mismatch as binary objective is used to predict variables belonging to 2 classes only (0/1).